# Get Element Of Array By Index in Typescript+React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

How can I get an element by index in Typescript+React? I keep getting the error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type '{ code: string; name: string; dateTime: string; }'. Maybe it's a stupid, but I don't have much experience with Typescript, and I would like departure[0] and then departure[1] to be displayed separately on the page

```
   const [result, setResult] = useState<ConversionData[]>([]);

    type ConversionData = {
    uuid: string;
    airlineCode: string;
    price: {
      amount: number;
      currency: string;
    };
    bounds: Array<{
      departure: {
        code: string;
        name: string;
        dateTime: string;
      };
      destination: {
        code: string;
        name: string;
        dateTime: string;
      };
      duration: string;
    }>;
    };
    useEffect(() => {
    const api = async () => {
      const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/flights").then((res) =>
        res.json()
      );
      setResult(data);
    };
    api();
    }, []);

    return (
    <div className="App">
      {result.map((value) => {
        return (
          <>
            {" "}
            <div className="container">
              {value?.bounds.map((newvalue) => {
                const departure = newvalue.departure;
                const destination = newvalue.destination;
                const dates = new Date(departure.dateTime);
                const dates2 = new Date(destination.dateTime);
                return (
                  <>
                    <div>
                      <img
                        src={
                          "https://d1ufw0nild2mi8.cloudfront.net/images/airlines/V2/srp/result_desktop/" +
                          value.airlineCode +
                          ".png"
                        }
                      />
                      {departure.code}
                      <br />
                      do {destination.code}
                      <br />
                      Xxx:
                      {dates.getUTCHours()}
                      Xxx:
                      {dates2.getUTCHours()}
                      <br />
                      {dates.getUTCDate()}-
                      {dates.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" })}-
                      {dates.getUTCFullYear()}
                      Xxx
                      {dates2.getUTCDate()}-
                      {dates2.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" })}-
                      {dates2.getUTCFullYear()}
                      <div className="line" />
                    </div>
                  </>
                );
              })}
```

[image: what I need to get]

I searched on internet and found solutions with keyof but it doesn't work

Comment: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type '{ code: string; name: string; dateTime: string; }'.` Looks like you're trying to access an object instead of an array by this error

Comment: According to your typings, `departure` is an object, not an array. If the intention of `depature[0]` is to get the entry for "Amsterdam Schiphol" and `departure[1]` is to get the entry for "Barcelona", you need to be using `bounds[0].departure` and `bounds[1].departure` instead, as `bounds` is the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a double mapp unnecessarily. I needed bounds[0].departure as in comment

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `data` object needs to be cast as the `ConversionData` type. When `fetch` returned the data, it's unaware of what type it is.

`setResult(data as ConversionData[]);`

You may first need to cast it to `unknown`:

`setResult(data as unknown as ConversionData[]);`

Comment: Per the [TypeScript definitions for `json()` in a `fetch()` response](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5c92af1dccda6495e35ca4b6ab4eafb1c0cdbf28/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L2592), Promise has a return signature of `Promise<any>`. `setResult(data as ConversionData)` would actually cause a type conflict because `setResult` is expecting a `ConversionData[]`, not an individual object.

Comment: You are very correct, thank you! That was an oversight - revised.